# EWS: How to update IsRead property of an EmailMessage

Tags: c#, asp.net, exchangewebservices

how to update `IsRead` property of an `EmailMessage` using EWS or other method?

Just setting `mail.IsRead=true` does not seem to persist.

Answer (score 12):

OK,no one answer my question after I post it for nearly 1 hour which is quite unusual, but I just found a solution. Hope this will help others who get confused on this issue.

```
mail.IsRead=true;
mail.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AutoResolve);
```

That's it. The key is you have to update the item or EmailMessage after setting IsRead property.

Comment: any idea how to do this using php-ews API ?

Answer (score 3):

A bit late but here is a more detailed code sample:

```
// if the property is not loaded yet, first load it
mail.Load(PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly, EmailMessageSchema.IsRead));

if (!mail.IsRead) // check that you don't update and create unneeded traffic
{
  mail.IsRead = true; // mark as read
  mail.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AutoResolve); // persist changes
}
```

Comment: how can I get a unique email item from the Item ID?